# SQL Trigger with Conditional Updates

Tags: sql, triggers, conditional-statements

I need to construct the following logic on a pair of SQL tables.  Here is the basic table structure:

```
TABLE [dbo].[Email](
    [IssueId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NoErrors] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmailBody] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    ...
)

TABLE [dbo].[Inclusion](
    [InclusionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IssueId] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

The primary relationship for both tables is an [Issue] table on the IssueId field.  Each Issue record has only one associated email table, but zero to many Inclusion records.

What I want to happen is this...

If an Inclusion record is deleted and it was the last Inclusion record associated with the Issue, then I want to set the Email.NoErrors to -1.  If other Inclusions exists (after the deletion) I want to leave the Email.NoErrors 'as is'.

I have written the following trigger that seems to work:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Inclusion_Delete]
   ON  [dbo].[Inclusion]
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE Email
   SET NoErrors = CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM Inclusion 
            WHERE IssueId = DELETED.IssueId
         )
         THEN NoErrors    -- Leave existing value
      ELSE
         (-1)
      END
   FROM DELETED
   WHERE Email.IssueId = DELETED.IssueId
END
```

There are two things that I know enough to worry about.  Firstly, the trigger seems inefficient as it always updates the Email.NoErrors filed, even if it doesn't have to.  Secondly, I'm aware that the DELETED reference table may contain more than one record but I am not sure whether my script would handle this correctly - but I suspect not.

Any advice/direction would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is the final code that I ended up with:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Inclusion_Delete]
   ON  [dbo].[Inclusion] AFTER DELETE
AS 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
BEGIN
   UPDATE Issue
   SET NoEmailErrors = -1
   FROM DELETED
   WHERE (
      Issue.IssueId = DELETED.IssueId
      AND Issue.NoEmailErrors != -1
      AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT * 
         FROM Inclusion
         WHERE Inclusion.IssueId = DELETED.IssueId
      )
   )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   UPDATE Issue
   SET NoEmailErrors = -1
   FROM DELETED
   WHERE (
      Issue.IssueId IN (
         SELECT IssueId FROM DELETED
      )
      AND Issue.NoEmailErrors != -1
      AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT * 
         FROM Inclusion
         WHERE Inclusion.IssueId = DELETED.IssueId
      )
   )
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rewrite may help you with the inefficiency concern:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Inclusion_Delete]
    ON [dbo].[Inclusion]
    AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Email
    SET NoErrors = -1
    FROM DELETED
    WHERE Email.IssueId = DELETED.IssueId
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 'x' FROM Inclusion 
            WHERE Inclusion.IssueId = DELETED.IssueId
        )
END
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, your code is much cleaner.  I have also found the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx which I think is relevant to what I am trying to do.  I have updated my original post to include the new script